# onmouseover executes on inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which is a wrapper for some text:

```
<div class="timeSpanWrapper" data-occupied="false">
    <span>@day.ToString("HH:mm", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK"))</span>
</div>
```

When I put the mouse over the wrapper, I want to execute a function:

```
$(".timeSpanWrapper").on("mouseover", function (evt) {
    if (evt.ctrlKey) {
        setTimeSlot($(this));
    }
});
```

The function gets executed, but it also gets executed if i hover the `<span>` within the timeSpanWrapper div, which is not what I want, as the method will be fired twice.

What is a workaround for this?

**Note:**

I tried the suggested answers. The method does not get executed when I mouseover the span, but it gets executed when i leave the span to parent div again, which is a problem as the parent div is a box with some text in the center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make sure it's not executed on child elements by ensuring the target is the bound element

```
$(".timeSpanWrapper").on("mouseover", function (evt) {
    if (evt.ctrlKey && this === evt.target) {
        setTimeSlot($(this));
    }
});
```

Or just use the mouseenter event, which seems more appropriate here

```
$(".timeSpanWrapper").on("mouseenter", function (evt) {
    if (evt.ctrlKey) {
        setTimeSlot($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: mouseenter was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.not()` function to avoid the span within:

```
$(".timeSpanWrapper").not(".timeSpanWrapper span").on("mouseover", function (evt) {
    if (evt.ctrlKey) {
        setTimeSlot($(this));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason why this is happening is that the mouseover event bubbles to it's child elements. you need to use `mouseenter` to avoid this.

try changing mouseenter with mouseover in the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/jpbax2xb/1/)

```
$(".timeSpanWrapper").on("mouseenter", function (evt) {
     $('body').append('<span>entered</span>');
});
```